# R: tree with overlapping strings

Tags: r, string, tree

My data looks as the following matrix:

```
verkoop          V621  
verkoopcode      V62123  
verkoopcodenaam  V6212355  
verkoopdatum     V621335  
verkoopdatumchar V62133526  
verkooppr        V6216  
verkoopprijs     V62162  
verkoopsafdeling V621213452  
verkoopsartikel  V62126324
```

Now, I want to make a tree in R as follows:

```
 V621   --> V62123  --> V6212355
        --> V621335 --> V62133526
        --> V6216 --> V62162
        --> V621213452
        --> V62126324
```

Or something like that. So that they consider overlapping substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `minimum.spanning.tree` function from the `igraph` package to create such a tree.

```
# load data
df <- read.table(text='verkoop          V621  
verkoopcode      V62123  
verkoopcodenaam  V6212355  
verkoopdatum     V621335  
verkoopdatumchar V62133526  
verkooppr        V6216  
verkoopprijs     V62162  
verkoopsafdeling V621213452  
verkoopsartikel  V62126324')
# use igraph package
require(igraph)
# create adjacency matrix 
adj <- nchar(sapply(df$V1, gsub, x=df$V1, replacement=''))
adj[!sapply(df$V1, grepl, x=df$V1)] <- 0
# name adjecency matrix 
colnames(adj) <- df$V2
# original graph
gr <- graph.adjacency(adj, mode='directed', weighted=TRUE)
# minimum spanning tree 
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(gr)
# e.g. for graphical representation
plot(mst, vertex.size=40)
```