# R: depth minimum spanning tree

Tags: r, tree, depth

In question [R: tree with overlapping strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213018/r-tree-with-overlapping-strings) I've asked to make a tree that looks like:

```
V621   --> V62123  --> V6212355
    --> V621335 --> V62133526
    --> V6216 --> V62162
    --> V621213452
    --> V62126324
```

It works with the `minimum spanning tree` from the package `igraph`, But now I want to determine the depth of each element of that tree. How coudl I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we borrow all the relevant code from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213018/r-tree-with-overlapping-strings)...

```
df <- read.table(text='verkoop          V621  
verkoopcode      V62123  
verkoopcodenaam  V6212355  
verkoopdatum     V621335  
verkoopdatumchar V62133526  
verkooppr        V6216  
verkoopprijs     V62162  
verkoopsafdeling V621213452  
verkoopsartikel  V62126324')
# use igraph package
require(igraph)
# create adjacency matrix 
adj <- nchar(sapply(df$V1, gsub, x=df$V1, replacement=''))
adj[!sapply(df$V1, grepl, x=df$V1)] <- 0
# name adjecency matrix 
colnames(adj) <- df$V2
# original graph
gr <- graph.adjacency(adj, mode='directed', weighted=TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol=2))
plot(gr)
# minimum spanning tree 
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(gr)
```

You can get the depth with

```
shortest.paths(mst, to="V621", weights=rep(1, ecount(mst)))
#            V621
# V621          0
# V62123        1
# V6212355      2
# V621335       1
# V62133526     2
# V6216         1
# V62162        2
# V621213452    1
# V62126324     1
```

Note that we have to adjust the weights because by default `graph.adjacency` used the values in `adj` as weights for the edges and really we only want to count each edge as one. You could have also done

```
gr <- graph.adjacency(adj>0, mode='directed', weighted=TRUE)
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(gr)
shortest.paths(mst, to="V621")
```

to set all the default weights to 1.

This assumes you know taht "V621" is the root node. If you didn't know which was the root node, you could find it with

```
dx <-degree(mst, mode="out")
root <- names(dx)[dx==0]
shortest.paths(mst, to=root, weights=rep(1, ecount(mst)))
```